# How to run JQuery mobile application on Android Emulator?

Tags: jquery-mobile, android-emulator

Am a new comer in JQuery mobile.I developed a simple application in JQuery Mobile using Netbeans and run successfully on desktop browser.But I want to check its fit for mob screen.So I want to run that app on Android Emulator.I just run Android emulator but I dont know how to call my project from where and how?please help me...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krishna to be able to execute jQuery mobile as a android/iPhone app you need a wrraper framework like phonegap/cordoba (cordoba is its new name.

[This](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/) is an excellent tutorial for windows platform. In case of iMac you will find more help (tutorial) on phonegap developer pages.

Basically phonegap acts as wrapper between HTML/JS and rest of mobile platform. Because of that you must create separate version for android and separate version for iPhone. It will also give you access to phone hardware like camera, compass etc.

If you need more help give me a comment and I will try to help you as best as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to launch your web browser under your emulator and then connect to your server. If you are running your jquery mobile web site on a local development machine, you can likely connect to it via IP address and port

Example:

```
http://192.168.33.10:65637
```

Comment: My application running on local machine.sir can you explain how to launch my web browser under android emulator and connect my server.?

Answer (score 0):

First of all host your created website into IIS or IIS7, for that copy paste your website folder into wwwroot folder in inetpub folder in c drive. this folders will be available after installing iis or iis7, after doing this go to your desktop browser(ie, opera, google chrome, etc).
then type this, "localhost/yourWebsitefolderName/" then press enter, if your website is opened in your local browser then you can try below thing to oopen it in your emulator.

Start your android emulator, in emulator open the mobile browser, then type 
"10.0.2.2/yourWebsitefolderName/"